# How to refer to some one comment or recommendation

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

My supervisor gives me a comment. I have to respond to her comment. In my report, I should refer to her comment. For example,

Comment ......

My response:

This has been inserted **as commented by the supervisor**.

Is this a correct and accepted English sentence?

Comment: What sort of report? is this an academic relationship where they are giving you advice on editing a thesis? or is it more kin to a work report, with multiple sources where you need to show proper accreditation for each bit ?

Comment: @Smock. Hi. Yes, it is an academic relationship where they are giving me advice on editing my thesis.

Comment: "My supervisor noted that <insert comment>" | Next paragraph : "<Response to comment>"

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sounds very natural to say "as commented by", although I can't find any sources to say it is incorrect.

I would consider:

> ...as suggested by...
>
> ...as recommended by...
>
> ...as recommended, in the comments, by...

Or alternatively, but I wouldn't recommend in this context:

> ...as commented upon by...

[Here](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/commented) is a good article on where to used commented.